# Reducing $\ell_1$ norm of non-full-rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, norms

I have two matrices ${\bf{X}}_{p\times r}$ and ${\bf{Y}}_{r\times q}$ with $r<\min(p,q)$. Matrix ${\bf Y}$ does not have full row rank (i.e., rank$({\bf Y})<r$). Can I build two new matrices ${\bf{X}}'_{p\times (r-1)}$ and ${\bf{Y'}}_{(r-1)\times q}$ such that the following three conditions hold:

$\bf{X}' \bf{Y}' = \bf{X} \bf{Y}$

$\|\bf{X}'\|_1 \leq \|\bf{X}\|_1$

$\|\bf{Y}'\|_1 \leq \|\bf{Y}\|_1$

EDIT: By $\ell_1$ norm of a matrix, I mean the sum of absolute values of its elements.

Comment: What do you mean by $\ell_1$ norm of a matrix?  The $\ell_1$ norm of the matrix thought of as a vector?  Some sort of induced norm?

Comment: The sum of absolute values of its elements.

Comment: Do you want an analytic answer, or will a numerical answer suffice? There is a standard-ish numerical way to try to solve these sorts of problems: Fix $X$ and find the $Y^\prime$ with the smallest $r$-th row subject to the constraints $XY^\prime = XY$ and $\|Y^\prime\|_1 \leq \|Y\|$. Then fix this $Y^\prime$ and find the $X^\prime$ with the smallest $r$-th column, and then iterate back and forth between $X$ and $Y$ like this until convergence. If you're lucky, you'll converge to $X^\prime$ with $r$-th column equal to $0$ and $Y^\prime$ with $r$-th row equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need an analytical answer; possibly a construction algorithm which builds $X'$ and $Y'$ from $X$ and $Y$, by some row or column operations.